# Solving a cubic equation in mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to solve a cubic equation using Mathematica of a rather complicated expression say $f(r,\beta,\theta)$ , and in terms of $r$ the maximum degree term that appears is of degree $3$ so I tried solving $f=0$ in terms of $r$. The problem is that when I look at the discriminant of the function in terms of $r$ this will be positive and when I do $Solve[f==0,r]$ mathematica returns me 2 of the values with complex numbers, so how can I fix this ? Is there a way where I can just ask it to apply the cubic formula ? Or just avoid the complex numbers at all since we have real roots? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the docs for reduce, there's an [example here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cubics.html) - try using option `Cubics->True` like this: `Reduce[x^3 + 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 == 0, x]` vs. `Reduce[x^3 + 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 == 0, x, Cubics->True]`

Comment: To filter out the Real only solutions, you could do something like `solutions=Solve[......]; Cases[solutions, y_ /; (x /. y) \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the solution will depend on $\beta$ and $\theta$ for certain intervals, I have tried doing something similar but the evaluation seemed that it wouldn't end.

Comment: You should post the expression $f(r,\beta,\theta)$ that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Are your results actually complex, or are they real numbers expressed through complex expressions? The latter are generally unavoidable if you seek expressions using radicals.

Comment: The expression is so complicated like 20 lines of a combination of a degree $7$ polynomial in $\beta$ and some trignometric functions depending on $\theta$, that I cannot tell if they are real numbers or not , I just saw that it has some complex numbers in the mix . I have tried doing the plot of the results using the expressions in terms of $\beta$ and $\theta$ but the graph just appears blank. @JohnDoty

Comment: Post the function...

Comment: Usually, a blank graph means that you didn't evaluate the expression to a real number. First, try substituting numbers for your parameters to get a number. Then try varying one of the parameters in `Plot` to get a graph.